# npm warn invalid config proxy config Must be a full url with 'http://'

Tags: node.js, proxy, npm

Please look into it as it is not working for me:

npm warn invalid config proxy http://'Accenture\username:userpassword@2017'@127.0.0.1:8080
npm warn invalid config Must be a full url with 'http://'

Comment: BTW: Posting your password here is probably not a smart move...

Answer (score 6):

Finally i got the issue resolved with the help from network guy

```
strict-ssl=false
proxy = http://ip address of proxy:8088
https-proxy = https://ip address of proxy:8088 
registry = http://registry.npmjs.org/
```

These settings should go in `~/.npmrc`, or in `/root/.npmrc` if you need to use `sudo`.

Comment: where is that file located?

Answer (score 5):

If you wish to change any of the configuration properties in npm, the section on config on npmjs.com is useful:
https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/config

The full proxy configuration for npm is

```
npm config set http-proxy http://username:password@proxy-address.com:80/'
npm config set https-proxy http://username:password@proxy-address.com:80/'
```

That should work for you, you can also double check it's set by typing
    npm config list

```
http-proxy = "http://username:password@proxy-address.com:80/"
https-proxy = "http://username:password@proxy-address.com:80/"
```

Further to that, if you prefer to edit the config file directly it is stored in a file called .npmrc that can be added either to each project root or the global settings in your user directory, please see the npmrc help content
https://docs.npmjs.com/files/npmrc

In relation to your question, if your password contains special characters, they need to be escaped. This url provides useful information on special characters:
http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/unix-linux-export-variable-http_proxy-with-special-characters/

As an example, if your password were P@ssword then it will become P%40ssword.

Comment: doing this is showing me error like 
npm warn invalid config Must be a full url with 'http://'