# React js: I tried installing create-react-app globally and i got this error

Tags: npm-install

```
sudo npm i -g create-react-app
```

> npm WARN invalid config proxy=""
>   npm WARN invalid config Must be a
> <
>   full url with 'http://' npm ERR! Unexpected end of JSON input while
>   parsing near '....0.2","minizlib":"^1.'

Then after setting my proxy i got  this erro

```
npm WARN registry Unexpected warning for https://registry.npmjs.org/: Miscellaneous Warning EMAXREDIRECT: maximum redirect reached at: https://registry.npmjs.org/
```

npm WARN registry Using stale package data from https://registry.npmjs.org/ due to a request error during revalidation.
npm ERR! Unexpected end of JSON input while parsing near '....0.2","minizlib":"^1.'

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/ace/.npm/_logs/2018-07-11T23_46_02_367Z-debug.log

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your npm configuration for `proxy` with `npm config list`. Your proxy is an empty string currently, delete it or change it to the proxy url you need to use.

Also see this: [npm warn invalid config proxy config Must be a full url with 'http://'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31985123/npm-warn-invalid-config-proxy-config-must-be-a-full-url-with-http)